# Parsing a JTPL block that has multiple sub blocks

Tags: java

I'm using JTPL (http://jtpl.sourceforge.net/) to parse HTML. When I have a block that will be repeatedly parsed and has sub blocks inside that block, the output seem to be flush data of previous iterations, except for the last sub block. I went through the source code of the library and found that there is a bug in the way template is parsed or may be the feature I'm trying is not supported. Did any face similar issue and fixed it with a patch ?

Following is my java program

```
import net.sf.jtpl.Template;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

@WebServlet("/sample1")
public class sample1 extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel {
        Template tpl;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                try {
                        out.print(this.generatePage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(out);
                }
        }

        private String generatePage() throws Exception {
                tpl = new Template(new File("C:\\Users\\stadikon\\Desktop\\sample1.jtpl"));
                tpl.assign("TITLE", "Sample 2");
                int line = 10, col = 4, altern = 2, count = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= line; i++) {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
                                if (count % altern == 0) {
                                        tpl.assign("VARIABLE", "section1");
                                        System.out.println("sample1 - before parsing section1");
                                        tpl.parse("main.line.section1");
                                } else {
                                        tpl.assign("VARIABLE", "section2");
                                        System.out.println("sample1 - before parsing section2");
                                        tpl.parse("main.line.section2");
                                }
                                count++;
                        }
                        System.out.println("sample1 - before parsing line");
                        tpl.parse("main.line");

                }
                tpl.parse("main");
                return (tpl.out());
        }
}
```

Follow is the .jtpl template

```
<!-- BEGIN: main -->
<html>
<head>
<title>{TITLE}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- BEGIN: line -->
    <table>
        <!-- BEGIN: section1 -->
        <tr>
            <td>{VARIABLE}</td>
            <td>Section1</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- END: section1 -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Dividing Line</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- BEGIN: section2 -->>
        <tr>
            <td>{VARIABLE}</td>
            <td>Section2</td>
        </tr>
        <!--  END: section2 -->
    </table>
    <!-- END: line -->
</body>
</html>
<!-- END: main -->
```

Actual Output:

```
> >
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
Dividing Line
section2    Section2
section2    Section2
> >
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
Dividing Line
section2    Section2
section2    Section2
> >
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
Dividing Line
section2    Section2
section2    Section2
```

Expected Output

```
> >
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
Dividing Line
section2    Section2
section2    Section2
> >
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
Dividing Line
section2    Section2
section2    Section2
> >
section1    Section1
section1    Section1
Dividing Line
section2    Section2
section2    Section2
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a separate template, parse it, write its output in string format to the original template.